# PHP on IBM Http Server

Tags: php, ibmhttpserver

Could you please tell me how to install PHP on IBM Http Server?

I have copied all php7 files into C:/php folder and added the following code to http.conf:

```
LoadModule php7_module "C:/php/php7apache2_4.dll"
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
PHPIniDir "C:/php/"
```

But when I start the server I get the following error:

"Windows could not start IBM HTTP Server V8.5 on Local Computer. For more information review the System Event Log."

In the event log I get the following:

"The IBM HTTP Server V8.5 service terminated with service-specific error Incorrect function.." Event ID is 7024.

Comment: Are you sure PHP is the culprit? The error mentions nothing about that.

Answer (score 2):

You should use fastcgi to connect IHS with PHP for this exact reason,
you really want the isolation between the two processes.  Most users of IHS
or Apache on windows do not have the skills/resources to debug native
crashes to find the incompatibility and these things are simply not
tested together.

IHS prior to V9 includes mod_fastcgi. IHS V9 and later includes mod_proxy_fcgi.  There's no shortage of guides on these on the web.

Comment: Exactly, like Apache web server, it requires to have listed installed modules in apache.conf, I suppose there is somewhat config on your web server that you should point your php installation. Moving from php5 to php7 is a bit tricky

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to use fastcgi, but apaches configurations are different than IHMs.

    LoadModule fastcgi_module modules/mod_fastcgi.so
    <IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
 #AllowOverride NoneOptions +ExecCGI  
FastCGIServer "c:/php/php-cgi.exe"
SetHandler .php
</IfModule>

Now I see the content of index.php in my browser. It is not executing. Could you tell me what is the problem?